# ItemTemplate: how to refer to the item itself

Tags: silverlight, xaml, data-binding

I have a ListBox displaying items with a template something like this:

```xml
<ListBox 
    x:Name="CustomerResultList"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <controlsToolkit:DockPanel>
                <Button 
                    x:Name="CustomerButton" 
                    Command="{Binding MyCommand}" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding WhatGoesHere?}"
                    controlsToolkit:DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                    Content="ButtonText" />
                <TextBlock 
                    Text="{Binding Path=Name}" 
                    controlsToolkit:DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
            </controlsToolkit:DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The button in the template should invoke a command that gets passed the customer as a parameter.

I can't figure out how to refer to the customer in the buttons CommandParameter binding.

Is there a special Elementname or Path I can use to refer to the Custome itself and not some of its properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding}"
```

If you specify `Binding` without `Path`, you bind to the `DataContext` itself.